# Retrieving form data and displaying it on a modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a table that displays multiple rows (each row is from a table on the database)...I have a button (with id view) on each row which should open a modal with the complete form data.

## This is my how I generate my table:

```
echo "<tbody id=\"tdata\">";
                     while($fetch= mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
               {    
                    //$table .="<tbody>";
                        $table .="<tr data-id=\"$det_Id\" id=\"dat_Row\" >";
                            $table .="<td>".$i."</td>";
                            $table .="<td>".$title."</td>";
                            $table .="<td>".$date."</td>";
                            $table .="<td>".$status."</td>";
                            $table .="<td class=\"btn-group\" style=\"border:none\">";
                                //<div class="btn-group">
                            $table .="<button id=\"view\" data-id=\"$det_Id\" class=\"  btn btn-primary \">"."View"."<span class=\" glyphicon glyphicon-expand\">"."</span>"."</button>";
                                        /**$table .="<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">";
                                            $table .="<li>"."<a href=\"#\" class=\"view\">"."View"."</a>"."</li>";
                                            $table .="<li>"."<a href=\"#\">"."Comments"."</a>"."</li>";
                                        $table .="</ul>";**/
                                //<!--</div>--> 
                            $table .="</td>";
                        $table .="</tr>";

                    $i++;         


                    }
                    echo $table;
                    echo "</tbody>"; 
                echo "</table>";
                echo "</div>";

                //end of while


           }
```

As u can see, I used the data-id attribute within each button.

### This is how I make the modal appear:

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        //Here, i am implementing a functionality that will show the user details of his/her submissions via the use of a modal 


        //get the form's unique identifier

       $(" tbody #view").click(function(e) {

             form_Id = $(this).attr("data-id");


       $("#myModal").modal({
          // backdrop:"static",
           show: false,
           remote:"./php/modalGet.php?form_Id="+form_Id

           });
          $("#myModal").modal('show');



           $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (){

               //im trying to debug here
                 alert(form_Id);

            });



        //alert(form_Id);
    });


    });
    </script>
```

### getModal.php (This retrieves the form_Id from the remote method and prints out the form to be displayed on the modal)

```
<?
include("../inc/connect.php");

//retreive id from the remote method
$det_Id =$_GET["form_Id"]; 

// Setup Query
$query = "SELECT `title`,`aim`,`overview`,`no_of_part`,`selection`,`advice`,`risk_part`,`risk_res`,`consent`,`findings` FROM `tbl_SubDets` WHERE `det_Id`=? LIMIT 1";

// Get instance of statement
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($mysqli);

// Prepare Query
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query);

// Bind Parameters [i for integer]
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'i',$det_Id);

 // if statement executes, bind the reult and printout table
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
{
    //alternative method: query parameters could be placed in an array and then "imploded" in here 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$title,$aim,$overview,$no_of_part,$selection,$advice,$risk_part,$risk_res,$consent,$findings);

            //echo "<form>";
           // Fetch Value
           while($fetch = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
          {
                  echo "<div class=\"form-group\">";

                    echo "<label for=\"project-aim\">"."Aim of Project"."</label>";
                    echo "<textarea class=\"form-control\" id=\"aim\" name=\"aim\" >";
                    echo $aim;
                    echo "</textarea>";
                  echo "</div>";

                   //Overview
                   echo "<div class=\"form-group\">";                   
                        echo "<label for=\"project-aim\">"."Project Overview"."</label>";
                        echo "<textarea class=\"form-control\" id=\"aim\" name=\"aim\" >";
                        echo $overview;
                        echo "</textarea>";
                  echo "</div>";
                  //num of participants
                  echo "<div class=\"form-group\">";                    
                        echo "<label for=\"project-aim\">"."Project Overview"."</label>";
                        echo "<input type=\"number\" class=\"form-control\" value=\"$no_of_part\"  >";                      
                  echo "</div>";
                  //selection
                  echo "<div class=\"form-group\">";                    
                        echo "<label for=\"project-aim\">"."Project Overview"."</label>";
                        echo "<textarea type=\"number\" class=\"form-control\" >";
                        echo $selection;
                        echo "</textarea>";                     
                  echo "</div>";
                  //advice
                  echo "<div class=\"form-group\">";                    
                        echo "<label for=\"project-aim\">"."Advice to Participants"."</label>";
                        echo "<textarea type=\"number\" class=\"form-control\"  >";
                        echo $advice;
                        echo "</textarea>";                     
                  echo "</div>";
                  //risk to participants
                  echo "<div class=\"form-group\">";                    
                        echo "<label for=\"project-aim\">"."Risk to participants"."</label>";
                        echo "<textarea type=\"number\" class=\"form-control\"  >";
                        echo $risk_part;
                        echo "</textarea>";                     
                  echo "</div>";
                  //Risk to researcher
                  echo "<div class=\"form-group\">";                    
                        echo "<label for=\"project-aim\">"."Risk to Researcher"."</label>";
                        echo "<textarea type=\"number\" class=\"form-control\" >";
                        echo $risk_res;
                        echo "</textarea>";                     
                  echo "</div>";
                  //consent
                  echo "<div class=\"form-group\">";                    
                        echo "<label for=\"project-aim\">"."How will Records of consent be changed"."</label>";
                        echo "<textarea type=\"number\" class=\"form-control\"  >";
                        echo $consent;
                        echo "</textarea>";                     
                  echo "</div>";
                  //findings
                  echo "<div class=\"form-group\">";                    
                        echo "<label for=\"project-aim\">"."How will the findings of this research be disseminated?"."</label>";
                        echo "<textarea type=\"number\" class=\"form-control\"  >";
                        echo $findings;
                        echo "</textarea>";                     
                  echo "</div>";


           }
           mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
          // echo "</form>";
}


?>
```

### This is the students page:

```
<section class="container" style="margin-top:150px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-4">
            <ul class="list-group panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard "></span></div>
                <li class=" list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>Proposals Sent<span class="badge" id="total_Sent"></span></li>
                <li class=" list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span>Pendiing Proposals<span class="badge" id="total_Pending"></span></li>
                <li class=" list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok "></span>Proposals Accepted<span class="badge" id="total_Accepted"></span></li>
                <li class=" list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove "></span>Proposals Rejected<span class="badge" id="total_Rejected"></span></li>
                <li class=" list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>Deadline<span class="badge" id="deadline"></span></li>

            </ul>
        </div><!--end of panel-->
        <div class="col-md-8" id="table">

        </div>  

    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" ><!---->

  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">


      <div id="subDets-Body" class="modal-body">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


    </section>
```

#### My problem:

Lets assume we have 3 rows (with data-id 1,2,3) I click on any button and the modal shows with data from that row but if I close the modal and click on another button from a different row, **the modal appears but the data displayed is still from the previous click**

Comment: You have to use append, to insert data on model. After showing the model, remove it's content using jquery empty.

Comment: @Sumanta736 do i pass "data" as the parameter?

Comment: You modal code and jquery code please?

Comment: can you make a fiddle of your code ?

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the right Id? what ar you having in your alert(form_id)?

Comment: @ChrisOnDaRocks i was using the alert to make sure that the form_Id was passed.....lets say i click the button with data-Id=1...after the modal retreives from the database, the alert shows "1"...but if i close the modal and click on another button(lets say data-Id=2), the modal still shows previous result....and the alert shows "1"...if i click ok, the alert then shows 2...its as if the modal has not deleted the previous click or something

Comment: Ok, looks like the show() method is triggered twice. I personally use jquery to do the ajax call, not sure about remote call inside modal()